# Visual Studio can't find Installed version of SDK(10.0.17763.0) for a solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2017

So yesterday when I reopened an old work solution/project it failed to compile with:

> "error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.17763.0 was not found.
> Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version
> in the project property pages or.."

The problem is: I do have that SDK version installed but it refuses to find it, but it finds the other older SDK version I downloaded today to check. But I need to keep this project in this SDK as its a group work and I'm the only one who experiencing this problem at the moment.

**My vs module installer and VS project retargeting**

[[image]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgPYQ.png)

So far what I have tried to solve this

- uninstall and reinstall VS 2017
- removing the sdk, and then re-adding it again

Comment: Check that the solution platform is set to x64.

Comment: Rechecked it - everything was set to x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could check whether the solution platform settings are consistent. For example, both are x64:
[image]

[image]

Second, you could set the SDK version in `Properties->General`. Then, check whether there is `10.0.17763.0` in `Retarget Projects`.
[image]

If you still don't have this version, you can try to find `Desktop development with C++`, uncheck the check box in the upper left corner, and check it again. Then modify VS and `Retarget Solution` angin.

Also, you could download the [Windows SDK 10.0.17763.0](https://developer.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/) directly.

Comment: Thank you so much.
So first two things didnt work. But when I manually downloaded and tried to install it, windows said it was already installed, so after removing it manually from Add/Remove, and than installing it from the pack directly, now it compiles in visual  studio.